# How can i access a form element using this keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have forms generated by loop, so the name of elements would be the same. That's the reason i want to use $(this) inorder to access them and compare. But unsuccesful as of yet, any ideas how can I.
FYI I am a newbie to Jquery, any help appreciated :)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("form").submit(function() {

 if ($(this).children("#textbx").val() < $(this).children("#comparetobox").val() ) {

    $("span").text("Validated...").show();
    return true;


  }

    $("span").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);
  return false;
});

</script>

<form id='userbid'  name='userbid'  method=post>
<input type="text" name="textbx" id="textbx">
<input type="text" name="comparetobox" id="comparetobox">
<span></span>
<input type="submit" value="save" name="submit">
</form>
<!-- Form is in loop so can be generated N no of times -->
<form id='userbid'  name='userbid'  method=post>
<input type="text" name="textbx" id="textbx">
<input type="text" name="comparetobox" id="comparetobox">
<span></span>
<input type="submit" value="save" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I have also tried `if ($(this).find(#textbx).val() < $(this).find(#comparetobox).val() )`

Comment: I think you don't understand jQuery selectors very well.  `$(this)` at the top level will be the document window wrapped in a jQuery object, not your form.  Also, the children selectors should be quoted, i.e. `.children("#textbx")`

Comment: yes @andrewmu I am a newbie to jquery learning with my mistakes. apologies for the same. Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you compare values of `input` boxes, but this is valid JavaScript code:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    if ($(this).children(".textbx").val() < $(this).children(".comparetobox").val()) {
        $(this).children("span").text("Validated...").show();
        return true;
    }
    $(this).children("span").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);
    return false;
});
```

Pay attention that ID of elements should be unique. Use classes instead (e.g. `.textbx`).

Comment: Thanks VisioN, It was a very silly mistake from myside. apologies for the same.

Comment: Thanks @VisioN it works fine now. My Jquery.js had the problem, replaced it with the latest version. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the second input you have 'is' instead of 'id', that might be your problem.

Comment: @Pruitlgoe still not functioning as required. any ideas why?